# Using Powershell to determine AD user's password complexity

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-10

I'm looking for a Powershell script that would allow me to see a list of AD users as well as their password complexity.

Details like having: "never expires" set and knowing when they last changed their password would also be a great asset.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "that would allow me to see a list of AD users as well as their password complexity." - no. That would defeat the purpose of deploying AD in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the available password-related information stored in ActiveDirectory for a user can be listed with:

```
Get-Aduser username -Properties * | Select *Password*
```

```
AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption : False
badPasswordTime                   : 132652374477430749
CannotChangePassword              : False
LastBadPasswordAttempt            : 5/11/2021 4:10:47 PM
PasswordExpired                   : False
PasswordLastSet                   : 5/10/2021 8:29:09 AM
PasswordNeverExpires              : False
PasswordNotRequired               : False
```

All passwords set by users must meet the Default Domain Password Policy requirements you can find here. The complexity requirements can only be viewed in the group policy editor though:

```
# Last policy change:
Get-ADObject -Identity (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).objectGuid -Properties whenchanged | Select WhenChanged

# Policy Settings:
Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy

ComplexityEnabled           : True
DistinguishedName           : DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=local
LockoutDuration             : 00:30:00
LockoutObservationWindow    : 00:10:00
LockoutThreshold            : 3
MaxPasswordAge              : 90.00:00:00
MinPasswordAge              : 30.00:00:00
MinPasswordLength           : 8
objectClass                 : {domainDNS}
objectGuid                  : 00000000-6cfb-4bea-ba1b-000000000000
PasswordHistoryCount        : 12
ReversibleEncryptionEnabled : False
```

Note that this policy does not apply to certain Admin roles using the function to set another user's password, nor does it apply to passwords which haven't changed since the last time the policy was updated.

If you have local admin access on a domain controller, you can absolutely dump credential hashes from it, try to crack them all, and check them for complexity. **Do not do this.** Bad idea to consider poking at passwords at all.

If you are worried about other people's password strength, set new requirements, expire the existing passwords, and move on.